# Cached file is not being fetched by the service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-config

When I try to access `http://localhost/visites/` it should fetch the precached file `visites/index.php` . So I guess I have to indicate somewhere that this particular route matches that file, do you have any idea on how I can do that?

I leave my SW code here just in case:

```
const cacheName = 'v1';

const cacheAssets = [
    'accueil.php',
    'js/accueil.js',
    'visites/index.php',
    'js/visites.js',
    'js/global.js',
    'css/styles.css',
    'charte/PICTOS/BTN-Visites.png',
    'charte/STRUCTURE/GESTEL-Logo.png',
    'charte/PICTOS/BTN-Animaux.png',
    'charte/PICTOS/BTN-Deconnexion.png',
    'charte/PICTOS/BTN-Fermes.png',

];

// Call Install Event
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
  console.log('Service Worker: Installed');

  e.waitUntil(
    caches
      .open(cacheName)
      .then(cache => {
        console.log('Service Worker: Caching Files');
        cache.addAll(cacheAssets);
      })
      .then(() => self.skipWaiting())
  );
});

// Call Activate Event
self.addEventListener('activate', e => {
  console.log('Service Worker: Activated');
  // Remove unwanted caches
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cache => {
          if (cache !== cacheName) {
            console.log('Service Worker: Clearing Old Cache');
            return caches.delete(cache);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

// Call Fetch Event
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
  console.log('Service Worker: Fetching');
  e.respondWith(fetch(e.request).catch(() => caches.match(e.request)));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include some logic in your `fetch` handler that accounts for this routing information:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
  // Use a URL object to simplify checking the path.
  const url = new URL(e.request.url);

  // Alternatively, check e.request.mode === 'navigate' if
  // you want to match a navigation to any URL on your site.
  if (url.pathname === '/visites/') {
    e.respondWith(caches.match('visites/index.php'));
    // Return after responding, so that the existing
    // logic doesn't get triggered.
    return;
  }

  e.respondWith(fetch(e.request).catch(() => caches.match(e.request)));
});
```